# Please don't write answers in comments

Tags: discussion, faq, comments, policy

I've been noticing a trend lately of people writing answers in the comment section. What does this mean? When you write an attempt to solve the OPs question - whether it's a fully fleshed out idea or not - and dump it in the comment box.

This is not good.

Answers in comments are detrimental to the site. Comments cannot be downvoted, only upvoted, and so you can't have the quality checks that answers have. You cannot edit comments to improve them after 5 minutes. You cannot accept a comment. If you answer in a comment, and the OP says that solved their problem, they may leave the site never to return and leave an answer unaccepted, if the commenter answered with what they had originally posted as a comment.

More importantly, **this is not what comments are for**. Comments are for *requesting more information and suggesting improvements*. It says so, right when you go to post a comment:

[image: see blockquote below]

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

A Community Manager, [Robert Cartaino](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/u/3), has been deleting a whole bunch of answers in comments. Let's take a look at [his recent comments](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino?tab=activity&sort=comments):

> @[redacted] If you have an answer, please post it below. You don't need to ask the author if they will like your answer before you post it... unless you need a specific point of clarification. Thanks.

> <many comments removed> If you have an answer, please post it below. Comments are here to ask for clarification to help improve the post, but they do not have the feature needed to properly vet whatever you say here. Comments are not for answers; answers are for answers. Thanks.

> @[redacted] If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

> **<comments removed>** You cannot close a question saying it does not belong here and then proceed to answer it in comments. That is the worst of both worlds.

> @[redacted] If you have an answer, please post it below. Links sending users elsewhere for that information doesns't *[sic]* help this site, and answering questions in comments only invites others to respond and doesn't actually help curate content that can be properly vetted. Thanks.

> @[redacted] Not everyone is qualified to answer every question (but they'll certainly try <grin>). But that does not make this a discussion forum. Telling people, "If you cannot answer my question, we'll just discuss it in comments" is not how this site works. If you welcome alternative-culture answers, that's fine, but as a (presumably) Q&A site we CANNOT have the "real answers" posted below and a 2nd-class of answers in comments.

...the list goes on.

So: **Please do not write answers in comments. They are harmful to the site.**

---

And if you *do* see an answer in a comment... flag it! You can select the 'other' field, and then write an explanation that this is an answer in a comment.

[image: using the other field to explain that it's an answer in a comment]

Comment: Or, as a quick "answering in comments" is how I usually flag these.

Comment: I've noticed that some of comments have been deleted even when they are not answers, but simply complimenting the OP on a good question and *also* asking for further clarification.

Comment: @Mari-LouA : when the clarification has been added, there's no need for the comment anymore. I usually delete mine, as well as others do, some just flag it as "not needed anymore". I agree we have to clean our own mess too :)

Comment: +1 good post!  Err, I mean.... [relevant meta discussion](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1524/2185)

Comment: @OldPadawan When such clarification has been added, I personally find it helpful for the comments to stay on for at least some time so that the other person who requested such clarification can know that it happened. It's the difference between me getting a notification in my inbox and then proceeding to reverse a downvote I may have likely placed, and then forgetting about it completely.

Comment: @Zizouz212 : to make myself more clear, I mean *I use a comment to ask OP for some clarification -> OP edits the question and all see it -> I delete my own comment as **no more needed** -> nobody has to read something useless anymore, and it cleans the page*

Comment: Well, for you, that's okay, because you yourself are deleting the comments. But I wouldn't want comments deleted if I haven't been offered the chance to know that clarification has been added.

Comment: Your parallel and very related question at ELU has become a [full-fledged debate](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10756/231519), @NVZ. I should like strict moderator action (read delete) on such comments as contain a partial answer (which the member is unwilling to post as a proper answer) but some users apparently *want to retain* answers posing as comments.

Comment: "You cannot close a question saying it does not belong here and then proceed to answer it in comments" I remember this one - my comment suggesting OP seek professional help got nuked too :/

Comment: Man. I really want to write a comment here answering this question, but it isn't actually a question.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I don't think that whatever policy English Language Usage goes with is relevant here. English Language Usage is a very different site: it's about a more objective topic, it has a different style of answers, and it doesn't have the problems with comments that we do here.

Comment: The policy of ELU may not be relevant here but in fact *they do have a problem with answers in comments at English.SE*, @Hamlet. The senior members got used to writing short answers as comments in certain circumstances where they didn't want the question to be answered (because it needs to be closed, etc) or if the answer lacked adequate citations. I feel that answers should not be written as comments on any site and there is no real excuse not to write an answer. This is also generic Stack Exchange policy of long standing and  I hope you don't disagree? We are right to be strict with it here.

Comment: I think there is no facility for making an observation about a question that the OP should consider, but is not exactly requesting a clarification or serving as an answer. Such as pointing out a logical inconsistency, or noting answers in another question that is not quite a duplicate have some bearing or should be reviewed, or many other such gray areas. I think comments fill that gap; as well as **partial** answers. I know from experience people DO down vote incomplete answers that may provide the OP a piece of the puzzle, which seems valuable to me but not worth risking a petty down vote.

Comment: @Zizouz212 If the concern was clairified in the question, there isn't a need for the comments.  If you want to know the history of the question, check the edit history.  But once the post is updated, the comment becomes unneeded, because there _is_ a record of the changes.

Comment: Related questions on other sites: [money.meta](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997), [photo.meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/34807)

Comment: Please tell me I'm not the only one trying to click the screenshot to post a comment!

Comment: @Vylix - I sometimes try to click my own screenshots :P

Comment: Downvoting comments is not as big problem as you picture, because if there are flaws in the comment, another comment may counter it and get more upvotes (and as a result also become more visible)

Comment: @SargeBorsch Um... and then we get a third comment telling them that they're wrong, and a fourth and the comment section turns into an argument... no. This isn't acceptable. Comments are not for discussion or writing answers.

Comment: I'm in agreement of flagging but can someone clarify if, for a single question, the mods prefer multiple flags singling out each comment, or a single flag with a custom message saying 'These comments all need reviewed as there are multiple Answers in Comments'?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland - it doesn't really matter. I personally prefer individual flags, while others prefer flags on the post. I think that the Interpersonal.SE mods expressed a preference for flagging the post, although I'm not sure.

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel I was really hoping for the collective consciousness that all high rep users have to kick in with a single answer! That's fine though, until there is a hard and fast rule I'll flag each situation as it presents itself.

Comment: On the one hand I'm very happy to see this post. On the other I'm very sad because I had an absymal response to my exactly the same request on other SE sites. :(

Comment: I've noticed another plague recently, answers in comments with a token clarification question. Example: "Was the grass green or blue when you were trying to solve your problem? Either way what I recommend is discussing this further with..."

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland then converting all of the sentences as questions will make them good again?

Comment: The placeholder text in the "add comment" textbox has changed now. Please update the screenshot with new image.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The answer to that is the “follow” feature. (Perhaps we need options to automatically follow posts after interacting with them.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So, I've been sitting and reading and thinking for some time now about what everyone's written in comments and answers here. I think I'd like to reiterate, emphasize, and expand on a point Arwen Undómiel brought up in the question.

Comments can't be downvoted or edited. That's important on a site like Interpersonal Skills. Answers here do more than just make a program more efficient or come up with a handy word or solve a math problem or make the universe a bit more understandable. Answers on IPS can change people's lives in major ways. They can make or break a relationship, a job, a life.

Think about that for a second. Stand up, walk around a bit and come back. Then think about it again, because it's *important*.

We can't have partial answers here. We just can't. Because poorly-thought-out remarks made by folks who can't or don't want to write a full, good-quality answer can be *dangerous*. If a comment-answer gets 9 upvotes, then maybe people think "Hey, that's a good idea! 9 other people like it!" But what if there are 30 other people who think it's a *terrible* idea but can't express it through voting? The comment gets visibility, even though it could be dead-wrong.

The only way we can combat this sort of problem is to nip it in the bud before it even starts to grow anew. That's why we need to delete answers in comments - or, really, just not let people write them in the first place. Allowing answers in comments will lead to crappy, half-serious answers that can cause real problems.

**If you're too busy or intimidated to write out a full answer, or don't want to think things through fully, or think it's just not going to matter . . . then don't write an answer in a comment.**

Comment: And before you ask us to only delete the ones that are actually bad, please remember that means you're telling us to judge the *quality* of content - which forces us to make judgement calls on what is good advice and what is bad. We can not do that. We can only *either* remove it all or allow it all and allowing it all would be untenable and obnoxious.

Comment: Thank you for writing this.  I probably _could have_ done something similar instead of basically going over it in comments on another answer here.  I mean really though, it's not like you're saying something that isn't true all over SE; but the great part is you made it obvious why it's _especially_ bad here.  I find it funny that people tried to argue the exact opposite.  I'm glad you came up with such a good way to explain why that's not the case.

Comment: -1 `They can make or break a relationship, a job, a life ... poorly-thought-out remarks...can be dangerous` Now comments can be life threatening, [good grief](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tCSdNNNlxrk/TgBQyMB6_-I/AAAAAAAAAEc/GudSBdVF7LQ/s1600/Picture%2B18.png).

Comment: May I suggest that you use the expression "harmful", `dangerous` is too loaded a word and overly dramatic.

Comment: How about an answer in a comment to a protected question by someone who wants to help but can't because he can't post an answer? This comment can change some lives in major ways. It can make or break a relationship, a job, a life. Think about it for a second.

Comment: Be that as it may, @Oleg, with each gem comes a mountain of crap. And as Catija said, we can't pick out the pearls from the sand. We can either allow comments in answers or not, and people seem to be pretty against it. Besides, very few questions are protected; you're talking about extreme edge cases.

Comment: Are you saying you can't give dangerous advice in comments, @Mari-LouA? I guarantee you that's not the case.

Comment: Of course dangerous advice can be given, and in those case I seriously doubt anyone sane would upvote a dangerous comment. And I am pretty certain more than one user would flag that dangerous piece of advice, and rightly so, and if that comment receives three or more flags, I believe the system automatically deletes it. (I'm not sure if it is 3 or more, but mods will be notified)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've seen comments suggest violence (maybe tongue in cheek, but e-sarcasm is hard) and get voted up.  The real problem would be advice that might seem good on first glance; but has a glaring flaw that has unforseen consequences.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1303/59

Comment: *"If a comment-answer gets 9 upvotes, then maybe people think "Hey, that's a good idea! 9 other people like it!" But what if there are 30 other people who think it's a terrible idea but can't express it through voting?"* = absolutely crucial reason to not tolerate answers posted as comments.

Comment: Meta is where site policy is fleshed out, @Kik. It would behoove those who disagree with the current policy to speak up and say why they disagree. But this is something that has been policy for years and years, and it seems like it's pretty popular on IPS, looking at the voting.

Comment: @Kik People left comments in answers because nobody considered that it might be a bad idea. Now that we actually have a policy established, I've seen occurrences of this go down, which should indicate the opposite of what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Kik - no, because even while people may be starting to do it less, **this is still a prevalent problem**. I've flagged a bunch of comments today for being answers in comments. This is still detrimental to the site, even if it's less widespread now. That just means that it's an *improvement*, but not completely fixed.

Comment: @Kik - it doesn't matter if everyone is against it, to be honest. It's a network-side Stack Exchage policy and is a fundamental rule for how SE works. If SE didn't have such strict policies on where to put specific responses, the quality would be a lot worse and it wouldn't be the site it is today. Also, please refrain from cursing on this site - all people here are expected to keep a professional tone and abide by [Be Nice](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Kik - re cursing: [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/294691). Re this topic: it's not arbitrary, it's there for a reason. This was actually posted as a reminder. If you want to contest it, leave an actual answer ;). If there's a sufficiently good reason network wide policies can be changed for a site, although I highly doubt that there will be any sufficiently good reason here.

Comment: There is nothing to suggest that the majority of users are against this, @Kik. Breaking a rule doesn't always mean one disagrees with it; it could be due to unawareness or simply forgetting about it. You're not pointing to anything that suggests that the majority of people support answers in comments.

Comment: If this Q was really posted as "a reminder" then please remove the "discussion" tag and add something like "proclamation", "imposition" or "ad auctoritatem" so it's more clear. ;) Thank you.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto There does seem to be some discussion going on here.  It already has a "Featured" tag.  If you look through all the answers and associated votes/discussions; it paints a pretty clear picture of why this policy is good here.  It _might_ benefit it make it a bit more clear that this is policy; but because the "Question" part was written by a normal user; it might be somewhat confusing on what is actual policy.

Comment: @JMac despite the fact that SE policy towards half-baked suggestions is exactly the opposite (i.e. don't convert to answers until the comment thread has finalized a suitable solution), my comment was not even directed at you. I am wondering why you deemed necessary to answer as if I were talking to you.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Anybody here is allowed to respond, (as I'm doing now ;) ) everything is public, you can't "direct" a comment at anybody what's important is the content. If somebody has anything to say with regards to the content of your comment he can do that. `discussion` is one of the 4 required tags, the other 3 are `support` `feature-request` `bug` I think it fits the discussion tag if you want to argue against it you still have to suggest one of the other 3.

Comment: @Oleg you are allowed to respond as long as you don't take a comment as a personal attack, especially if said comment wasn't even written to you. A discussion assumes listening to the other part. Stating a policy without any chance of talking about it is not discussion. I am not against appeals to authority when talking about moderation, it's the entire point of moderation. But it should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Nobody attacked anybody, JMac explained to you why the discussion tag is justified. I explained to you why he was justified to respond to you and that your suggestion is not possible, you can't just remove it, a question must always have one of the 4 main tags.

Comment: Oh don't worry, you don't have to patronize. I am perfectly familiar on how meta works. But thanks for caring.

Comment: This is a good answer, except for the part where you suggest that badly written software cannot be dangerous.

Comment: Anyone who takes random *on-sentence-answers* from the *comments-section* from *strangers* of the *internet*, lives a dangerous live anyways - *rigorous deletion will not safe them*. Also, try say something stupid in the comments an see how quickly you will have rectifying answers from someone who knows better. I think if there is something controversial, moving it to chat like they do in workplace.se is much more justified

Comment: @Daniel Moving comments to chat is [largely reserved for longer discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237983/274942) - and [it can't be done more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266693/274942). If they build up, they're noise, distracting from comments doing [what they're supposed to do](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) - requesting clarification, for instance. Leaving answers in comments invariably leads to side conversations and a more forum-like discussion, which isn't what SE is for.

Comment: How do you enforce this policy? Specifically, I'm wondering how many comments are deleted automatically (via user flags) vs how many need moderator intervention to delete (e.g. because they don't get enough flags or even any flags).

Comment: I agree this site's advice could be life changing, and has potential to steer people down one path or another. However I disagree entirely with your stating "*We can't have partial answers here. We just can't.*" - this I find to be contradictory to your first point. If information is potentially life changing then leaving out even a tiny bit of info could cause a massive difference, including being detrimental to their decision. I made a fairly relevant question about that https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/ips-specific-comment-requirements-why-comments-can-be-useful

Comment: You're talking on a deep phycological level about words on the internet can potentially change someone's life, and that can easily happen in an answer as much as a comment. A nice, informative answer *seemingly* to non-professionals to be positive and would help, but instead for whatever reason triggers a negative response in the asker (or anyone reading it). You cannot go down this physiological debate too much otherwise the only people who could legitimately answer would be those with phycological training and full background on those asking.

Comment: @user3114 “-1 `They can make or break a relationship, a job, a life ... poorly-thought-out remarks...can be dangerous` Now comments can be life threatening, [good grief](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tCSdNNNlxrk/TgBQyMB6_-I/AAAAAAAAAEc/GudSBdVF7LQ/s1600/Picture%2B18.png).” Well, they can be! Just as much as any other message. That comment was upvoted 6 times. I think that statistic highlights the danger of comments.

Answer (score 13):

### UPDATE 11 October 2017

I am today, more than ever, convinced that @Arwen Undómiel post is unduly alarmist in saying: *Answers is comments are detrimental to the site [sic].* The answers in comments that the OP fears and that all or some of the mods strive to delete in their valiant campaign are, in the end, counter-productive in the long run.

To illustrate my point, I shall provide a recent example:

[How do I ask my friend for some of his water on a long bicycle ride without offending him?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/how-do-i-ask-my-friend-for-some-of-his-water-on-a-long-bicycle-ride-without-offe)

Under the OP's question I had posted a single line comment. Something along the lines of

> "What about a lightweight backpack?"

Now I don't consider that comment  to be an answer because the OP specifically asked:

> **How can I ask my friend if I'm allowed some of his water without getting into an argument or offending him**,…?

My comment was not an answer, it was *only* a helpful suggestion and I was also implying if carrying a backpack would be possible in those circumstances. And because I have never ridden a professional bicycle in my life, I could not draw upon my own personal experience but in Italy, bicycle racing (*Giro d'Italia* is perhaps the second most important international cycling competition) is a national sport, and semi-professional/amateur cyclists a recurring road hazard during the long summer months. In all my years as an Italian motorist, I could not recall seeing amateur cyclists, who sometimes ride in small packs, carrying a backpack. My suggestion was deleted, along with three other comments, which I did not read in time. Deleted because it was an "answer". Rubbish. It was nothing of the sort.

A second idea occurred to me, one which had not been mentioned by anyone else, it was an idea, but I had learned my lesson. So, I wrote an answer which addressed the OP's specific question, and squeezed my suggestion around this "fake" answer. I didn't lie, but I could not say I used this particular solution. I hadn't. Ever.

Is this really what the site wants? Users who have to contrive answers so their suggestions can remain on the page longer than five hours?

### In Defence of Comments

Here's an excellent reason why partial answers or helpful comments are not indicative of “bad” or “lazy” users. The following defence and explanation  is taken from an EL&U [user ab2](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10793/44619) who brilliantly wrote

> (2) **For some** (not all) **questions, there is a stage where something like brainstorming goes on.** Possibilities are tossed out in comments, people read the comments and someone's brain goes "click!" and an answer emerges. Face-to-face meetings often have a brainstorming stage, before the participants settle down to propose serious solutions. This preliminary stage would be impossible if everyone had to submit a fully researched answer at the outset. Each person would have too much invested in his answer to consider tearing it up and going off on a tangent inspired by a couple of words of comment from a stranger.
>
> This can be summed up in one word: cross-pollination. Cut off cross pollination ruthlessly, and you don't get the best flowers (answers).

### CLARIFICATION

The point I was making, and I thought very clearly too, is **whenever a question has attracted three or more answers the OP is never going away empty-handed.**

Many questions on SE Interpersonal have five, six and even ten answers. This is quite extraordinary for any SE site, and I have been a member of EL&U and ELL for well over four years. The only time you see 5 or more answers are in Single-Word-Requests. Why? Because there could be more than one answer.

Likewise, there is room for more than one answer on any given question on IPS. I have yet to see a comment from a community member telling an author of an answer that the question has already been answered. This is a typical criticism when an OP has accepted an answer that has attracted already dozens of upvotes, and frequently there is only one correct answer. This doesn't happen here. Which is great.

### Answers in comments?

**It is my humblest opinion that helpful comments on IPS are not meant to be answers. They are just meant to be *suggestions* to the OP.** However, if some users are determined to delete helpful comments because they are interpreted as "answers" then watch the number of perplexed users asking in meta why their comments were deleted rise, and the number of users, new and old, dwindle over time.

IPS is not [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) where a user/visitor posts a question that requires *the* answer, or if you prefer, the single best solution.

IPS is a different site, there isn't *the* answer to every problem posed.

If there was only one right answer we wouldn't be seeing 3, 6 or as many as **[18 answers](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A18)** posted. I've been reading a lot of questions the past couple of weeks, I've yet to see a useful comment whose sentiment wasn't repeated or paraphrased in one or more answers.

For example, [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/should-i-always-ask-a-dog-owner-before-i-pet-their-dog), which attracted many comments suggesting more or less the same solution. In spite of this, the OP received 9 answers, 7 of which say pretty much the same thing. However, the “best” answer (the fourth one submitted) rose to the top, and this happened *despite* the presence of three answers–agreeing on the same course of action–and the helpful comments.

### Personal Experience

I've seen *real* answers in comments posted on ELL and EL&U. Very often an answer on the aforementioned sites can be as short as one word or consist of a single sentence. On IPS a single-word-answer would be impossible to submit because the questions themselves are not asking for a one word solution.

In addition, one-word-answers cannot be posted on *any* site. SE, in its infinite wisdom, prohibits link-only answers, users with less than 50 rep from posting comments, and it also imposes a minimum limit of 30 characters. What does this do? It constrains users, especially newcomers, to post answers.

The main and fundamental difference between IPS and other SE sites is that answers on IPS do not consist of a single word padded out in a sentence with ten or twenty words. And I cannot believe no one acknowledges this simple truth.

---

### Original Post

There have been **520 questions** posted to date (September 9th 2017)

Currently there are **16 questions with 0 answers** of which **[13 are closed](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers%3A0%20closed%3Ayes)**.
The search box tells me that three questions remain open but have yet to receive any answer. [Source](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano)

However, on closer inspection, it is only one question that has zero answers.

1. https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/what-could-i-have-done-better

There are currently **[336 questions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers%3A3%20closed%3Ano)** with **at least 3 answers**.

of which [**37 questions**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A12%20closed%3Ano) have at least ***12* posted answers**

### Conclusion

Over half the questions posted on this site have three or more answers. Where exactly is the problem?  Users are posting answers. Questions, even really bad questions, receive answers.

IPS has an excellent track record, probably the best of any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I read your edits. Still unclear to what question you are answering. This meta question isn't really a question in the first place. It's an announcement, a reminder.

Comment: @NVZ OK. That's a fair criticism, I'll accept that. I disagree but it's understandable. In essence, I am saying that the problem of answers in comments is not a problem. The limited number of characters means a complete full answer can never be posted in one comment. But if it is spread out over 3 comments then that is effectively an answer. Either ask the author to convert it into an answer or flag it. I would like to see examples of these said "answers" in comments which have deterred others from answering.

Comment: Surely, we flag and delete answers in comments. But saying that most IPS questions have a lot of actual answers doesn't give us the license to write answers in comments, if that's what you're getting at. I'm tempted to flag this as Not An Answer. ;)

Comment: Oh, okay. So that's probably something you should add into this answer itself.

Comment: This answer ignores all of the other reasons why answer comments are bad. It also doesn't really take into account that IPS situations may have several viable "solutions" so the posted answers may still fail to convey the solution posted as a comment, which leaves the site poorer in the end.

Comment: @Catija if you were to ask me to give you examples of "answers" posted in comments, and I mean real answers, not tentative suggestions, on EL&U I could find three or four after a few minutes of searching. If you were to ask me to give you the names of users who most often writes these comments=answers I can immediately give you at least three.

Comment: (Cont.) Now, I keep asking users to give me examples of open questions that did not receive answers. No one has so far. Now I'm asking you, @Catija, an expert of the site, to show me where a question was effectively answered in a comment that was not repeated in one or more answers. I really sincerely think this concern about answers in comments is a misapprehension. The OP who posted this "announcement" also tagged it with **discussion**. I'm allowed to discuss the concerns expressed by the OP.

Comment: Just because we have some answers to the questions already, it doesn't make it reasonable to post answers as comments.  Comments are _not designed_ to function as answers.  They are inherently less noticeable and less permanent.  Also (very importantly), they _cannot be downvoted_.  If someone posted a bad answer as a comment, it could still accumulate positive score if a few people vote it up.  The only way to combat it is to post more comments that refute it; but then you have to read through the discussion to determine if it even is a good answer.  It's bad practice, and there's no benefit.

Comment: @JMac helpful comments are just that, they;re meant to help the OP. They could be fleshed out into full and proper answer if the commenter feels encouraged. Then  again when a question receives five or more answers the OP has a good choice and the community REWARDS good answers with **rep**. No rep, i.e. upvotes and downvotes,  is earned in a comment upvoted even 20 times. There is more gratification in earning rep than seeing a comment upvoted. And if the comment is bad, it doesn't get any upvotes. For exampl, see my comments on this page not one upvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But what if someone gives _terrible_ advice but gets two upvotes on the comment.  Someone can walk by and think "oh, people agree with that advice!", when in reality there could be collapsed comments underneath saying it's terrible.  It's not about the user rep, it's about the quality of information you're giving them.  If you have some advice that fits into another answer, AFAIK you can suggest they elaborate on it in their answer; so that the information is there _and_ in the proper format.

Comment: @JMac  Then the awful misleading advice can be flagged by the community and deleted. And if the OP has got 5 or more answers that kinda offsets the terrible advice with its measly 2 upvotes. Answers in comments is a problem on other sites, not so much here. Have you seen the length of some of the answers? Impossible to fit in one comment, it has to be spread out over several comments.

Comment: @JMac if someone asks how do they convince their spouse to listen to them? I can mention marriage counseling as a possible idea. Or I can say talk to your friends, that is what friends are for. That comment is probably replicated in one or two more proper answers. But by itself it's not an answer, it's a helpful/unhelpful friendly/patronising free piece of advice, which someone else can take and expand if they want to.  IPS has an enviable record, I'm asking the OP "Where is the fire"? I don't even see any smoke.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This isn't just Interpersonal.SE policy that the situation pertains to, it's the entire site.  We do not want comments as answers, because comments are designed for a different purpose and cannot handle answers.  Writing a very basic comment without detail giving someone advice isn't really useful.  You can either take the time and elaborate on why you think it works, or just let someone else post it as an answer.  There's no real benefit to posting in comments without justification.  Why would they follow advice if it isn't backed up?  Basically, redundant comments aren't helping.

Comment: Mari-Lou, have you seen my meta question about how many comments have been deleted on this site? The only reason you think they're not a problem is because we've been so proactive in deleting them. From [Shog's answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1553/36), as of two weeks ago, there were *a total of 2373 comments deleted, 1412 on questions and 961 on answers.* A good number of those 1412 question comments were answer comments.

Comment: Paradox:it's apparently not yet a serious problem at IPS.SE (or maybe, *not apparent* as a serious problem at IPS.SE which is probably because of the many answer-comments deleted by @Catija and other mods) but *answers as comments are not discouraged enough where they should be (read ELU)* and some members, recently on NVZ's meta Q have made eloquent but for me unconvincing arguments why answers *can be* posted as comments! I don't think policy need vary from site to site on this matter when network policy is so clear:so IPS.SE is totally right to deal strictly with answers posing as comments.

Comment: @Catija the reason why I think comments as answers is not a real problem on this site is that I can see how many questions receive more than one answer. Many of these answers overlap, some add a slightly different slant, others are more detailed and go deeper into the issues. Rep is awarded to answers not comments. Privileges are awarded to users who reach milestones. Badges are awarded for excellent answers. The "gaming" element of SE rewards users who post answers not helpful comments or real answers.

Comment: It's not about gaming the system or the length of answers.  If you have an answer to give; SE requires you to use the proper channels for several ingrained reasons (discussed in the many meta threads on the main meta).  This is especially important here IMO, because it's easy to give advice in the space of a comment;  but next to impossible to also justify it there.  By posting answers in comments; you basically can only post an "answer" while avoiding any backup to the statement.  So either they blindly follow your advice, or they ignore it because you didn't justify.  Neither is good IMO.

Comment: @JMac Sorry "gaming" is then the wrong expression, I was trying to come up with the one that means the ploys and tactics Q&A websites use to encourage users to keep participating.

Comment: @JMac I feel I am repeating myself, the whole point of my post is to say: "Look! Actually, answers in comments is not a real big problem on this site." I objected to Arwen Undómiel's melodramatic tone in her public message. People are *answering* questions. And if they're not, it's not because there are answers in comments. E.g. please look at the 300 rep bounty I have placed on a [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/what-expressions-or-phrases-can-i-use-to-close-jewelry-sales-with-female-custome) that currently has 5 downvotes and was recently reopened.

Comment: [cont.]  That question still received an answer, but I believe it deserves better answers. I am doing my little bit to help users. I am not against the system. Please stop making it out that I am. It's simply not true.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If people refuse to answer because comments do; that helps my point.  It goes around the system. even though comments are immune to down votes and generally don't have room to back up their statements, making them poor answers.  If the comments were deleted, the answer quality likely would increase because people would not feel discouraged for "repeating" others.

Comment: @JMac group all the points you are making into an answer, please.

Comment: Ironically, I didn't tempest the OP with comments. I actually followed the SE guidelines and posted an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't feel the need to submit an answer to this meta post, because this is more of a reminder than a question.  I don't know what I would post as a relevant answer, it is already contained in the body of the "question", I. E. Don't post answers in comments.  If you're trying to point out of irony of me "answering" this  in comments, it's worth noting that the meta rules around it are different.  That is because the meta often has discussions that go back and forth, and when kept on topic it's an appropriate place for the discussion AFAIK.

Comment: ELU culture is totally different. Quoting it doesn't add much, imho, to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating and undeleting this answer which deserves to be read @Mari-lou A. I am personally opposed to the practice of posting answers as comments but your arguments are pertinent and therefore I upvote!

Comment: Why would we leave a comment that duplicates what is already in half of the answers? Most of the answers on that question already say to carry extra water - so your argument that it's not an answer because it's not an IPS solution would invalidate at least part of the content of half the answers. Also, again, *comments are not for discussion* suggesting a non-IPS solution is discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a StackOverflow user, sometimes I see an interesting question in the 'Hot Network Questions' feed and check it. Sometimes I have something useful(or just want to post something) to say and then I post an answer or a comment.

This happened with a question on 'interpersonal', I interpreted the situation differently than all the answers and wanted to post an answer because I believe it can help OP **but** the question was protected and I can't post. Don't know who made this decision but somehow a completely new user who answered one question and received one upvote should be trusted more than a relatively long time user with good track record on this network, very logical. OP offered me to answer a different question and then she would've upvoted my answer so I can post but this is silly and I refuse to participate in this silliness.

So what can I do? I answered in a couple of comments, they were removed before she could see them(this happened before what I described earlier) posted another comment and then after she asked me about it posted again an answer in a couple of comments, this time she saw them before they were  deleted and though it wasn't as good as my original answer I mostly said what I wanted.

All of this was made much more difficult than it should be by the deletion of my original answer in comments, the protection of the question and the decision to not let me post in a protected question.

Is this an answer to this non question? Don't know but maybe it can be useful. In general I find the fight against comments on this network silly and futile, it's akin to prohibition, just give people what they want, they will do it anyway.(not currently offering alternatives to the attitude towards comments, when people will be willing to change things many good ones can be discussed)

Comment: You can see who made the "decision" to protect the question on the question - it was protected by the Community user because it had too many answers too quickly including three deleted answers, one for being abusive, one for being low quality and one self-deleted. The question also currently has 86 deleted comments. So, no... I don't think those all need to stay. Many of the comments (about 40), including yours were moved to chat, so they weren't completely deleted. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/65394

Comment: The explanation for when a question is protected automatically can be read on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109116/284336 and the general FAQ for question protection is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question If you feel that a question is wrongfully protected, you can flag it and the moderation team will consider whether the question should remain protected.

Comment: @Catija The decision I was talking about was the decision to make my 100 points not real. Your explanation about why it was protected is not relevant. This: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238296/bug-cant-answer-protected-question-if-received-association-bonus-earned-10-r is a relevant link and I find the reasoning for this decision illogical. Only my second answer was moved to chat the first one was deleted before OP saw it.

Comment: That is a network-wide rule, so complaining about it here serves little purpose.

Comment: Does this one help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129223/ ? As the answer there states, the solution is to avoid overuse of the protection. Unfortunately, I agree that the question should have been protected in this case. But it doesn't have to remain that way forever.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, I saw that one as well and no it doesn't help. Having a completely new user with 10 rep being able to do something that a StackExchange user with > x (let's make x 3000 so it won't be about me) rep on a different site makes absolutely no sense. Please don't tell me that my comment serves no purpose, my only purpose with it was to respond to you I'm not going to go argue with Shog9 about it.

Comment: Your point is very pertinent @Oleg -- yes, the network needs to reconsider the rule that association bonus is not sufficient to post an answer to a protected question.

Comment: @EnglishStudent No, that's the whole point - you need to have participated a little bit to be able to answer protected questions - that's the entire reason for protection, so new users who don't know the site well can't post poor answers.

Comment: @Tim No, the whole point(my whole point) is that new users who don't know the site *at all* ***can*** answer protected questions. Somebody who asked one question and received 2 upvotes knows jack shit about this site. Someone who uses this network for a long time is much more likely to post a good answer.

Comment: @Oleg oh right sure, but protection is just to filter off the 95% who know nothing. The other 5% can be manually dealt with.

Comment: Oleg rightly says that the system should have more confidence in an association bonus member's substantial experience elsewhere on SE network and not treat them par with a brand new user when it comes to (not) answering protected  questions @Tim, necessitating such a newly associated user to post his answer as a comment -- but again a solution to this will need a network-wide decision on this matter.

Comment: I got 95% of my rep on Academia SE by answering a protected question. I just had to politely ask a mod to unprotect it first, then I answered. No big deal.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It wouldn't have helped in this case, but yes this is a good suggestion. I still think that it shouldn't be necessary for moderately high rep network users.

Comment: I just had exactly the same issue on a "protected" question.  I have a good answer, I have experience on many other networks - why can't I post it?  So I'm stuck with a comment.

Comment: @Tim, but answers have "quality control" because they can be downvoted - if the answer by the new user indeed will be so poor, it will be downvoted and we won't have the problem. Disallowing to answer and discouraging to comment will make users from other sites look at it, then go away. The automatic link "why don't you answer these other questions" is silly and invites half-assed answers just to get to the level of answering the original question.

Comment: @Richlv Not sure why we're still having this conversation, but the protected feature is there to improve quality. If you have **evidence** that the protected feature reduces quality by encouraging poor answers, show it. Otherwise, let's assume Stack Overflow know what they're doing WRT moderation on this network.

Comment: @Tim I'm also not sure why, probably another protected question was featured, people have good answers, can't post them, post them in comments, their comments get deleted and they find this post. Anyway you completely twisted the argument. The official stance is that questions are protected to prevent low quality and spam answers. My reputation on another site proves that I'm not going to do that. The claim that a user with 10 rep is more trustworthy than me is ridiculous and insulting, if you're going to make it the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @Tim, we are having this discussion because the policy apparently seems detrimental to people. I did not claim (not sure anybody did) that it encourages poor answers - I suggested it eliminates answers and possibly pushes people away from the site altogether. I claimed that the "answer these questions to ramp up rep" popup encourages half-assed answers. So next time I'll just prefix my non-answer-comment with "Could you please clarify whether...". Also, adding smileys in the middle of a comment looks weird, so here you go ;)

Comment: @Oleg actually, there's no burden of proof. This is the SE policy, and they choose the policy. I'm explaining why they chose it.

Comment: @Richlv "half-assed answers" = "poor answers" I think. So you did claim ir causes poor answers. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Oleg yes, I am paying attention. He claimed it causes poor answers. And I claimed, overall it improves quality. He made the first claim, that it causes poor questions. I’d appreciate it if he shows that there are lots of new users posting poor answers just to answer a protected question. If he provides proof, I’ll happily find evidence of it being there to improve quality. Please read my comments before trying to explain why I’m wrong.

Comment: @Tim After rereading, you're right, my bad. For some reason I assumed we're talking about *protected* questions in comments to my answer about *protected* questions don't know why. Now when I actually understood you a couple of points. To be precise Richlv said encourages not causes, not the same thing. No reason to assume SO knows what it's doing meta exists to discuss that and sometimes improve things. And even if in this case they do know it doesn't mean that the stated reason for not counting the association bonus and the real reason are the same.

Comment: @Tim, I specifically mean the popup that suggests somebody goes and answers other questions just to get the rep to answer the question they wanted to answer. This might encourage me to go and answer "something" just to get one upvote, somewhere.

Comment: @Richlv If it gets an upvote, it's an answer we want on this site normally. That's a good thing.

Comment: The association bonus should be addressed in it's own meta post, not here. However, creating good answers in one stack does not mean you will make good answers on another, and as such, the association bonus should NOT count to get over the protection. The stacks are different enough that they should be kept separate. Especially with IPS. One upvote here is not hard to get, so go answer another question and come back later. I've seen way too many spam answers from people with the association bonus to think it has any value over the new user with one upvote.

Answer (score -7):

By expressing your thoughts as questions rather affirmative sentences, they will become improvements and suggestions and fit perfectly the comment section.

Comment: Not necessarily. Just because a comment is in the form of a question is not sufficient for it to be considered requesting clarification.

Comment: how about something like "do you think X is best for you?"

Comment: "Clarification" refers to clarifying the *question*, not clarifying whether or not the OP thinks a potential answer is good.

Comment: @Cascabel that's a good point. But still, why isn't it suitable? I think the form "have you tried X?" is common?

Comment: @Ooker Just because it's "common" doesn't mean it's good or desirable.