# Answers in comment: do we get notification when our answer-comment got deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

[Please don't write answers in comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/please-dont-write-answers-in-comments)

Sure! But I think deleting the comment before the person is actually able to convert the comment to an answer is bad. I believe people will forget what they just said in the comment, and thus we lose a potential (good) answer.

**Do we get notification, and ideally our answer-comment, when it is deleted?**

If not, I think mod should message the user their comment and ask to convert it to answer.

---

As an alternative, maybe ping the users that have answer-comments, and wait 24-hour before deleting them. It will be great if there is **a delayed-deletion feature for answer-comment!**

Comment: We are not notified of the delete @Vylix because we are not supposed to post answers as comments in the first place. It's my job to see whether I just did that.  So when I post a comment I will then read it to see whether it looks like an answer to the question. If it does, then I will post it as an answer and usually delete the comment. (This rule is interpreted somewhat differently for the purposes of meta here.)

Answer (score 13):

**No, we don't get notified when our comments are removed.**

Although sometimes CMs and mods *do* leave comments to notify the users encouraging them to post an actual answer, it is not to be expected of them. They are doing a favor.

The best approach is to *know beforehand* that all **comments are ephemeral**. If it is to be later added to an answer, take a copy of it right then and there. It may be removed any moment.

A delayed-deletion feature sounds like a question fit for MSE, and probably already asked there.

Comment: "we don't get notified when our comments are removed."  and it looks like they're blown away good and proper, too, not just set with a "deleted" flag.  I could have sworn that I'd commented on an answer, it got removed, so I checked database.

Answer (score 0):

So I just literally posted this comment under OP's question here, read it over like I always do and OMG found it was an answer posted as a comment! Seeing this I am posting this answer-in-a-comment **as an answer**, as we all should, and will later delete the comment:

> We are not notified of the delete @Vylix because we are not supposed to post answers as comments in the first place. It's my job to see whether I just did that. So when I post a comment I will then read it to see whether it looks like an answer to the question. If it does, then I will post it as an answer and usually delete the comment. (This rule is interpreted somewhat differently for the purposes of meta here.) – English Student

Comment: I suggest, instead of posting as a comment then reading, you read first and then post as appropriate! Not only will it save you having to correct your mistakes it'll also save you time and allow you to move on and answer / comment on more questions. :)

Comment: You are technically right, of course, but it is a method of writing from my own perspective and then reading from another user's perspective, which is easier for me *after* I post the comment @RyanfaeScotland. We often write comments spontaneously and post it. Not all comments read like answers but some do. I like to read the posted comment as it would appear to any other user. Only if the comment reads like an answer (which happens maybe 1 in 30 comments at most), I will post it as an answer and delete the comment.

Comment: You can still do that, write it in the comment box below the answer, give it a minute and then come back and read it as if it is from another user's perspective, just don't click Add Comment until you have! You don't have to do anything different except not post it. :D Of course I'm just suggesting it and won't push this method any further, if you really like to comment -> read -> adjust I'm not going to stop you (well, I might end up flagging between the read and adjust cycle but that's the risk you take!). :)

Comment: *"You can still do that, write it in the comment box below the answer, give it a minute and then come back and read it as if it is from another user's perspective"* __ Nice suggestion which I shall be sure to try out, thanks @RyanfaeScotland!