# Why was my comment deleted when it asked for clarification of a question?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

In the question [Politely refusing to validate veiled bigotry](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13194/politely-refusing-to-validate-veiled-bigotry), I asked (after, admittedly, having a somewhat lengthy discussion in the comments with the OP, which the mods duely deleted, and which I want to apololgize for) the OP for clarification about his question and suggested that he clear up a couple of issues.

In particular, I asked him to explain how the example he provided fits in with his question, which I couldn't make out, since he appears to ask how to adress bigotry without calling it that, and in a polite way, but never tells us whether he is talking about a discussion with the bigots themselves, or just people influenced by the bigots. His question seems to say the one thing and his example the other.

That comment survived the moderator action, as I thought it should, since it was as a suggestion for improvement (and explicitly so.) It was this comment that the OP answered with

> "This is a tactic that is used by a well known white nationalist, he
>   uses it in order to get people to not dismiss him as a bigot, one time
>   my own stepson was taken in by this tactic. How do I politely address
>   this tactic? There's the tl;dr for you."

which still leaves me wondering who he is trying to adress.

Now my comment is gone. I cannot reproduce it here, because it's gone, but I thought it was reasonably nice and helpful.

I was wondering whether it was deleted on purpose, and there was something wrong with the comment, or whether it just disappeared due to moderators deleting whole swathes of comments in one go.

Comment: The answer here is relevant and I think you should read it: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2817/36 Let me know if it doesn't help somewhat.

Comment: And the content of your last comment was: *But if your stepson thinks that Spencer isn't a bigot because he stands up for free speech, that's a grade A logical fallacy. Your commitment to free speech, true or professed, doesn't make you any more or less of a bigot. There's no need to refuse to validate anything - you show him how you can be both a bigot and a defender of free speech (or at least call yourself one). So I don't see how that makes anyone dismiss Spencer as a bigot - apart maybe from whataboutism. – sgf 21 hours ago* I'm sorry but I don't see a question there.

Comment: @Catija Yes, that was my repsonse to the OP's response to my comment. He appeared to believe that my question was already answered in the OP, and I replied with this. I was talking about my comment immediately before that (if I remember correctly). It starts something like "Could you please elaborate/clarify/some other such word". I think I understand the reasoning behind deleting comments in general by now, and especially that the policies are adhered to more severely here than on some other SEs, but I don't see how they apply to my comment. Sometimes I still miss it.

Comment: Most of your previous comment was discussion, not a request for clarification. At that point, it was your 9th comment on the question... long past time to be in a chat room.

Comment: @Catija I agree, and so the discussion was deleted, as it should have been. After it was deleted, I made one (1) comment asking for clarification and suggesting what I considered an improvement, and a follow-up comment to the OP's response. Both of these survived, without any accompanying discussion, for around 24 hours, but are deleted now. (The OP's response, however, is not.)

Comment: @Catija But if your point is that there were so many comments that you, or some other mod, deleted them without looking to hard, point taken. Just asking.

Comment: We're not near done with that question and its answers. There are 47 outstanding comment flags on them... It's a lot to work through, as HDE said in his answer.