# Clarification on deleted comment

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

On this question: [How to tell/ask my brother to provide his own food?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/22181/how-to-tell-ask-my-brother-to-provide-his-own-food)

I added a Comment similar to: Do you think you're over thinking this a bit?  "I'm not Mom and this isn't a restaurant, deal with it.  See you at 7."  Sibling relations aren't such that politeness isn't a primary concern.

It was deleted with no explanation.  I'm wondering why?

If it was an Answer in Comment, I'd be happy to point that out or reword to be more commenty.

Since it's a sibling relationship, to give the best advice, it would be good to know why OP thinks politeness is so important.

Answer (score 11):

Your comment was flagged and subsequently deleted. It was like

[image]

Looking at your comment, it seems like you are kinda answering the question in the comment. Especially when you skip the first sentence.

We have a [policy](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/29) to avoid answering in comments. Therefore, a user flagged this and it was removed. If you can just ask for clarifications or suggest improvements in the comment section, feel free to do so. But everything else other than this will be removed without any explanation.

Comment: Too bad.  On other sites, mods will recommend a comment be converted.

Comment: @Johns - with the sheer number that pop up here, that's simply not possible to do.

Answer (score 3):

AJ has done an awesome job [explaining *why* your comment was deleted](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3730/11811), but it looks like you're also asking why it was deleted **with no explanation.** In response to that, I think [this answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2810/11811) sums it up swimmingly:

> Short of a diamond mod actually telling you, there's really no way to know [that your comment was deleted].
>
> If you suspect comments are being deleted unfairly by the community, you can flag the parent post for moderator attention and they can look into it. But comments on the whole are treated as third-class citizens, so they're pretty much by design allowed — expected, even — to disappear without so much as a howdee-doo.