# Why was my relevant comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

[How can I communicate my issues with a potential date's pushy behavior?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/how-can-i-communicate-my-issues-with-a-potential-dates-pushy-behavior)

It was not rude or abusive, and about how men need unambiguous signals from women.

Answer (score 6):

Your comment was not about asking for clarification or suggesting improvements. It was just a reply to another commentator. We have [a strict policy](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/29) on using comments **only** for asking for clarifications and/or suggesting improvements.

As per [the Comment Privilege section](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment),

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Your comment wasn't any of above, so that's why it was deleted. And you don't have to worry about it being rude or abusive. It wasn't deleted for this reason.

[image]

Comment: No other site that I'm a member of is this picky.

Comment: Yes, we know. We have to put a strict comment policy in place due to heavy discussions, answers in comments, and even rude/abusive comments raised due to the discussion. Although, we are adhering to SE's comment policy.

Comment: You're filtering out a lot of useful statements.

Comment: If they're useful and can help OP finding their solution, then why not put it in an answer?

Comment: Would you accept a one line answer with no citations?

Comment: @RonJohn because of the nature of the topic IPS is about, we can't afford to have a loose comment policy, otherwise we'd have hundreds of comments saying "hey, this is worth trying" or "your motives are wrong, you shouldn't try to achieve this". We've had this new policy for more than a year and it has brought many good answers with citations, because restricting the usage of comments invited people to express their feelings in a (backed up) answer instead.