# Why were my two comments censored?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I wrote a comment about this question:

[How to ask a man to not take up more than one seat on public transport while avoiding conflict?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/22964/how-to-ask-people-to-not-take-up-more-than-one-seat-on-public-transport-by-mansp)

I was basically reminding OP that not only men take extra space because OP's message was sexist. I think that sexism can be applied both ways and not only men against women.

I was just trying to say that OP's message was sexist against men and I was censored in a few minutes.

---

EDIT: a few minutes later, another comment asking OP to specify where they were in France, because **in some places in Paris they could be beaten** and answerers should know this, was also censored. Seriously guys! It was a serious **life saving** advice that OP should be aware of, and you guys just censored it?!

Comment: For anyone looking to answer, it seems these are the two comments OP made: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/63296?m=51733008#51733008), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/63296?m=51733530#51733530) (the latter being the one about Paris being unsafe).

Comment: We have a strict comment policy on IPS, accepting only those which ask for clarifications or suggest improvements. In your case, it seemed you challenged OP's opinion, which you can do of course... as long as it's in an answer and that you explain why they should review their point of view. See [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/does-ips-moderate-comments-differently-from-the-rest-of-the-network) for more info on comment (community) moderation.

Answer (score 9):

It's not censorship. Comments aren't intended to be permanent, no matter what they offer, and SE policy is generally such that "censorship" isn't even a consideration on deleting comments.

In this particular case, there are two reasons, as best as I can tell here:

1. The comment was a challenge to the OP's framing, but did not adhere to the policy that comments are to be used *only* for suggesting improvements to the question. Crucially, the OP considered the suggestion and declined to change the question. Whether or not you agree with that decision, the comment served its purpose and so there was no need to preserve it.
2. This specific issue was discussed in chat, though I wouldn't expect any given user to come across that and be aware of it. I only know about it because I, too, made a comment about the specificity of the word *manspreading* in the question and was given a [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51734210#51734210).