# Should the "comments are not for extended discussion" message be upgraded?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

When I posted [this](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/could-we-take-measures-to-alleviate-some-of-the-exasperation-from-deleted-commen) question some of the members of the community suggested I should extract this particular point into another question so everyone could weigh in.

In this network comments are handleded in a stricter way than in other Networks. This makes people confused, because they think they are doing everything as they always did, so their comments should be accepted, and they fail to realize that in other Networks moderation of comments is more lax and their comments were actually against the rules.

However, people, as general rule, are here to help. Any time I wrote a comment in no way I was doing it to troll the other person, whether the comment was following or not the rules of the network I meant it well. So having your comments so consistently deleted without even an explanation or only the very cold "comments are not for extended discussion", when in other Networks this is handled totally different can be extremely shocking. In other networks you get the "extended discussion thing" when there are 20 comments or more, so you easily understand it and even feel a tad guilty. Here I have seen it happen with 3 or 4 comments.

**I think we should update the message "comments are not for extended discussion" to something along these lines to help users understand better why their comments are being deleted here while maybe they wouldn't in other sites:**

> In IPS we follow closer the rules for comments, please read them [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).
>   Comments shouldn't be used for extended discussion, if you wish to
>   discuss further with the OP you can open a chat. Please [read here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/does-ips-moderate-comments-differently-from-the-rest-of-the-network) for
>   more details on why we do this. Thanks a lot for your
>   collaboration!

I picked two links that I think could work, but I am open to any suggestion on the wording and links to be used.

PS: I am not native English speaker so I am sure this wording can be greatly improved. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Can you quote the message you're referring to? I'm not sure if you mean a system message or the "stock comment" users have been posting, that is in my answer on your earlier question (which was also added [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3851/3171))?

Comment: Hey @EmC  I can't find it, I actually created the other post before you added your quote there. But I was away so I couldn't do what Tinkeringbell and the other asked me to do untill now (openning this question) I am searching but I can't find it. However I remember in the past seeing when someone deleted a buch of comments (well 3 or 4) to add a message like "comments are not for extended discussion". (cont=>)

Comment: (cont=>) @Tinkeringbell suggested to open a question to define this specific comment because in the post of Comment Templates they were discussing many different comments. You actually linked AElis that has no votes and you didnt link yours that has more votes.

Comment: Yeah AElis just pasted in the one that I had been using, and I guess nobody felt strongly enough about it to vote (0 votes total). There is also a default message posted by the system that reads "Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat." (with a link) if mods have moved comments to chat. We can edit either one, but that's why I was wondering if you had an example :)

Comment: "*Hello network visitors! Please note that IPS is fairly strict about using comments as intended. Comments are only for clarifying and improving the question. Partial answers or general thoughts about the situation may be deleted without notice. If you'd like to write an answer, make sure to check out our posts on **How do I write a good answer?** and **citation expectations** first.*" (from @rainbacon I believe, somewhere on IPS, can't remember where exactly...)

Comment: @EmC Ahh I didn't know there were 2 messages, but yes I mean the message that feels kind cold when your comments have been deleted. I asume it is the system one you are referring to.

Comment: There's also another message shown by the system to users who converse back and forth in comments: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to continue this discussion in chat?"

Comment: @gparyani wow, there is a lot of messages. I think the best would be to have a more general better detailed message so people could empathize more with the way comments are handled here.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments here, there are a number of messages that you might see related to chatty comment sections!

1. [Here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3851/3171) is a comment that users have been posting under questions which were selected for "Hot Network Questions":

   > Hello network visitors! Please note that IPS is fairly strict about [using comments as intended](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). **Comments are *only* for clarifying and improving the question.** Partial answers or general thoughts about the situation may be deleted without notice. If you'd like to write an answer, make sure to check out our posts on [How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/) and [citation expectations](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/) first. Thanks!

   This one is totally manual, so if you think it could be improved, feel free to either edit or add in a new variation to that answer (it's Community Wiki so anyone can do that).
2. If the mods have noticed a chatty comment section, but feel it's worth creating a chat room for, they can move comments to chat. When they do that, the system automatically adds a comment that reads:

   > "Comments are not meant for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat."

   Sometimes we just leave it as is, but mods do have the ability to go back and edit it afterwards, like I did [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6481/what-pronoun-to-use-when-talking-about-a-transgender-persons-past/6484#comment93045_6484). Personally I do think the system comment is a bit blunt and it can be useful to edit it with more context, so people understand why and which type of comments were moved (e.g. "if you want to keep discussing [controversial-point-or-tangent], please do so there").
3. If two users are commenting back and forth, the system will automatically suggest to them

   > "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

   <sup>[examples in this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274514/would-you-like-to-automatically-move-these-comments-to-chat-could-be-clearer)</sup>

   This message is only shown to the users who are involved in the discussion and is just part of the StackExchange interface (aka not editable).

   If a user clicks the link, the system creates a chatroom and posts a comment on their behalf:

   > Let us continue this discussion in chat.

   <sup>[example](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23310/how-to-explain-that-some-of-my-difficulties-wont-improve-with-my-effort-or-by-t/23315#comment93967_23315)</sup>

   This is an automated comment as well and I'm not sure that regular users are able to edit it afterwards. You can always manually post another comment if you feel the need to explain. But if you're just browsing and see a comment like this posted by a non-diamond user, rest assured it was a voluntary action taken because the user wanted to keep chatting - no unfriendliness intended :)

Since 2 and 3 are built into the system, if you'd like to propose changing those that would need to be a feature request on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), since it would affect all sites.

Comment: Thanks for covering all the posibilities in your answer. I feel that the manual one is the one that need a tad of editing. It says here we are strict with comments, but it doesn't give a sense of how our strictness can be perceived different than in other SE sites, which I think is the problem sometimes we encounter. After all they probably think mods and such are strict with comments in other networks too. Do you suggest I add a answer here, or how?

Comment: @Mykazuki you could edit [the comment template post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3851/3171) to add your wording as a second option. Or if you want to ask for feedback / discuss something else before adding it, you could self-answer here first, up to you :)

Comment: I will post here then, I need to think a message. Thanks for your input!