# Can we improve upon the Be Nice policy here as a model for the rest of SE?

Tags: discussion, be-nice

Premise:
I think that SE as a whole is not nice enough.  But I also think that the people of SE are in general a great bunch of people.  There is a difference in the way that we communicate that creates conflict. ***I believe*** that problem is magnified here because this SE is a practical metaphor for the problem.  The questions we face here are often times asking how to resolve problems that exist through out the SE format.

And most of it revolves around our individual interpretation of [Be Nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

I also believe that we as a whole would like the site to be welcoming to everyone.  We just all need to shift our perspective a little bit to overcome this difficulty.  I also believe that just a few minor tweaks can change the entire network into something that is not just Great, but something that is transformative in all of our daily lives.  I know that my participation here has definitely improved my ability to communicate.  I suspect it has most people.

Specifically these I believe we can address these 2 points:

> Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.

and

> Don't be a jerk.

Is there some way we can slightly alter this to get a more desired result of less conflict, and acceptance of our differences?

Update - RE:

> If you frequently see rude/abusive comments, that means the comments
>   aren't moderated well, and that we need to revisit the comment policy
>   and what we'd allow based on be-nice. Same for answers: if they're
>   regularly being used as soapboxes for opinions, you could make a rule
>   that everything needs a back up or is subject to removal *([comment
>   source](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/can-we-improve-upon-the-be-nice-policy-here-as-a-model-for-the-rest-of-se?noredirect=1#comment7799_2761) but may be removed as it is a comment)*

*If you frequently see rude/abusive comments, that means the comments aren't moderated well* - This.  But the problem is not the moderators but the rules in which we expect them to arbitrate.  If we can give the mods a more appropriate set of guidelines, as well as giving the people the appropriate set of guidelines(boundaries) then we can solve this problem, or at least make it more manageable and improve the over all experience.  Most of the time comment arguments appear to start over one mistaken interpretation, then others jump in picking sides.  If we can stop the jumping in I think we can stop most of the bickering.

Comment: Can you please give some examples of the sorts of conflict you're describing?

Comment: @RichardU I'm asking because I don't see everything that goes on here and may have missed the incidents that are being referenced here, and because the same may be true of a lot of other people reading this. Also, it's not just about when there's conflict; it's about when that conflict stems from the interpretation of the Be Nice policy.

Comment: @RichardU It's a good idea to have examples as part of the question so that people can understand the context of the question without needing to have been there to see how bad the comments got before they were deleted.

Comment: @RichardU I don't think I was around for the question you are talking about. There are plenty of other examples of people not being nice on this site. This question would be improved by bringing up some specific examples so that everyone can be on the same page about we are talking about.

Comment: Guys Please stop bickering in Comments to my question. Take it to [chat]

Comment: Ehh... is this about discussing the need for a new/revised be nice policy, or about suggesting what should be changed? Because usually we have the discussion first, and only start suggesting changes and voting on them in a second meta post?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - The proper way to follow the SE process is if you disagree with the idea posted you down vote the question on meta.  Meta a downvote is not about the quality of the question or answer but rather agree or disagree with the premise.  Then the step after this would be posting a proposal for the FAQ.

Comment: @sphennings - I focused the question on my perception it is a problem.  If you disagree that it is a problem the proper method is to vote.  Voting is a wisdom of the crowd solution.

Comment: I'd like to know why you think there is a problem. Saying "I think" is entirely subjective and non transferable. If you provided some examples of the problems you are seeing we could then have a discussion about how to fix these specific problems, rather than hope that everyone is on the same page about what the problem is.

Comment: @sphennings - No I do not want to call anyone to the carpet here.  That is not the intent of the question.  The intent is to improve the site as a whole.  If you disagree with the premise then I suggest you downvote .

Comment: If you don't want to link to specific situations, that's ok. Could you instead describe in general the sort of behavior you are seeing, so that we can get on the same page.

Comment: I have downvoted this, and also voted to close it as unclear what you're asking here: suggestions for a new help center text, guidelines on how to be nice or if you want to discuss the actual need to change the help center text.

Comment: I don't understand why you are resistant to posting examples in your question, but posting an example in your answer is fine.

Comment: @Beofett - Because I calling out a specific set of problems in the question tends to limit the question responses to those specific problems.  I am attempting to address a larger set of problems with the culture of SE.  This is just the place that I see that could benefit most from it due to my lack of engagement due to my desire to avoid the conflict altogether.

Comment: It would help if we knew what that "Specific set of problems" were. Could you [edit] your question to list what they are?

Comment: @sphennings - That is the thing it is not a specific set of problems I am trying to address.  Rather trying to move the mountain so that we are addressing the problems before they happen rather than after they become an issue.

Comment: I understand that, but in this case, you seem to be saying our community is not nice enough.  That's very general, and unless we can understand *why* you feel the existing "be nice" policy isn't sufficient, and *in what ways* it is currently failing, it becomes difficult to have a focused, meaningful discussion.

Comment: Note that current answers range from "stay on topic" (paraphrasing) to "positive/negative vibe" to a "call out culture".  These all seem rather disparate to me, and none of those answers seem to suggest a single solution to a problem.

Comment: Also, you're now asking if we can improve... as in, is it technically possible for a site to have their own version of be nice... You can either ask whether it should be done (and make your arguments for why it should be done, together with the set of problems such changes should remedy) or you can use your question to suggest a change, because it solves a specific problem... Right now, it's still unclear to me what the goal of this question is..

Comment: @Beofett - I have updated the question does that address your concerns enough?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - I updated the question please reread and ask if you have any more questions.  I think I am on to something huge. I know what I am thinking, but I also know I may not be giving enough information.  I want to avoid getting bogged down in specifics, and focus on improving something that is already good into something great.

Comment: I appreciate what you're trying to do, and I do think the edit helps, but I don't know that it helps enough. To clarify: your premise seems centered on conflict over differing interpretations over the be nice policy. My perception is that the conflicts **I personally notice** are more based upon ideological differences, where each side sees the other side's *entire perspective* as fundamentally "not nice".

Comment: @Beofett - I believe the problem is not the be nice policy.  But rather our interpretations of it.  I also believe we can tweak that policy in a way that is transformative to remove the ideological differences as something that is permitted to be addressed directly.  I also believe that as a community we can address this issue and find that transformative solution.

Comment: @Beofett - Based on the comment above do you feel you could edit this question into something acceptable to the community?  If we can figure it out here I would take it to Meta.SE.  I am not ready to do that yet.  But I think there are enough minds here to figure this out.  And also to figure out if what I am missing, or if I have a solution looking for a problem rather than a solution to an existing problem.  The more black box we can make this question for that result the better I believe.

Comment: I don't know if I can.  My concerns are two-fold: one is that *I am part of this dichotomy*, and I have been unable to find a way to present my perception in any other way than "I'm right, and the other side is wrong". I see no benefit in any discussion that stems from my inability to reconcile with an opposing viewpoint. The other concern I have is: are you and I even talking about the same problem?  I truly don't know.

Comment: *I believe the problem is not the be nice policy. But rather our interpretations of it.* > that's why it's more important to make *rules* based on the policy (like [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2346/1599) for question scope for example). If you frequently see rude/abusive comments, that means the comments aren't moderated well, and that we need to revisit the comment policy and what we'd allow based on be-nice. Same for answers: if they're regularly being used as soapboxes for opinions, you could make a rule that everything needs a back up or is subject to removal

Comment: I think this may indeed be a case of 'hey, this could be a solution to ... rude comments/bad answers/ questions asking for opinions instead of skills ... but then you'd need to make the case of how a be nice policy would be the way to fix it, what would be interpreted wrong about it that can allow such behaviors

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - *what would be interpreted wrong* I do not know that we can address that. but I think we can address avoiding the interpretation in the first place.

Comment: I'd love to see that, but about all things are interpreted in one way or another... If you do think there's parts that regularly are misinterpreted though, it might be good to use those as an example, put in the meta question also the way they are misinterpreted and the behavior that misinterpretation leads to... and then we can either discuss the suggested change in term of whether or not it will actually solve the problem, or if it's the right way to go about changing the problem ;-)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - I really think that is better addressed in the answer.  This is the discussion portion, not the FAQ proposal.  What you are requesting sounds more like an FAQ Proposal.

Comment: Okay, so with that last edit, I think I'm starting to get it now: You're proposing we edit something into the Be Nice policy on how people interpret posts on this site (like questions or answers) and the kind of comments they leave based on those misinterpretations, and you want to get rid of those comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a stupid idea that seems people hate the idea

Comment: @WeAreAllInThisTogether It's not off topic. Just because people are responding poorly to your idea doesn't mean that there isn't merit in discussing it.

Answer (score 6):

> *If you frequently see rude/abusive comments, that means the comments
>   aren't moderated well* - This. But the problem is not the moderators
>   but the rules in which we expect them to arbitrate. If we can give the
>   mods a more appropriate set of guidelines, as well as giving the
>   people the appropriate set of guidelines(boundaries) then we can solve
>   this problem, or at least make it more manageable and improve the over
>   all experience. Most of the time comment arguments appear to start
>   over one mistaken interpretation, then others jump in picking sides.
>   If we can stop the jumping in I think we can stop most of the
>   bickering.

I think that this hits on the heart of a lot of this site's problems.

Comments are the venue in which the vast majority of the disputes and conflict I've witnessed occur.

Arguing over who is right/wrong, debating over why one perspective or another does or does not have merit, and questioning motives behind questions or answers **do not help this site**.  But it seems to happen over and over again, particularly for certain topics.

The "be nice" policy *already covers this*, and our moderators regularly step in [to delete comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1553/2185).

Unfortunately, deleting comments is a topic that upsets a number of users.  Worse, a number of users seem to take deleted comments as a personal challenge.

I've seen moderators delete comment chains, then post a typical moderator notice on the comments reminding users to not abuse the comment system, only to have comments continue.  I've seen moderators post much sterner moderator notices, such as:

> If you disagree with a post, write your own answer and let the community vote on it. **DO NOT USE COMMENTS TO ARGUE WITH A POST**. Future comments must **ASK** for clarification or suggest a specific, actionable improvement or they will be removed.

In [the example the above quote comes from](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/12763/2185), the response to this sterner warning was... to [engage in extended discussion about the answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75615/discussion-on-answer-by-jane-s-how-can-i-avoid-the-awkwardness-of-a-returning-pl), but with an attempt to phrase disagreement as a request for clarification.

Prior to the comments that were moved to chat, I saw a couple of other comments that were since deleted that also were arguments about the answer.

**People don't seem to care that certain types of comments cause conflict, and freely and consistently ignore moderator directives**

I know that moderator actions involving warnings and bans is not something they can or will share with the community, nor should they, so it is possible that they're already doing this, but I believe that the solution to this problem is for moderators to warn, and then suspend, repeat offenders, or those who ignore or attempt to bypass the moderator messages.

If this pushes some people away, **good**.  I firmly believe *we're already losing people* over these conflicts.  If we have to lose people, I'd rather lose people who deliberately ignore or seek to subvert the established guidelines.

Comment: If y'all are curious, there are 51 comments deleted from that post with the stern directive. 25 from before the quoted message, 20 between it and HDE moving the new comments to chat, and six deleted since then... and, sadly, that's not even a record. We have posts with >100 deleted comments. To give a sense of scale, the moderators (in response to flagging) have removed over 15,000 comments from this site. That excludes comments removed by the OP or by three user flags.

Comment: *warn, and then suspend, repeat offenders, or those who ignore or attempt to bypass the moderator messages.* This is literally penalizing the customers who need this site the most though.

Comment: @WeAreAllInThisTogether The purpose of an exchange isn't to help people. That is a side effect of the explicit purpose of an exchange, which is to create a repository of quality questions and excellent answers. What else do you suggest that we do with users who after being taught the rules refuse to follow them?

Comment: @sphennings - Citation Needed.

Comment: @WeAreAllInThisTogether I suggest you take the [tour] then. It's in the third sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> I also think that the people of SE are in general a great bunch of people.

Hopefully true :)

> I think that SE as a whole is not nice enough.

Absolutely. I think this could be because a lot of people come to SE *partly* (even if *subconsciously*) to get a bit of excitement from pushing their views and perhaps shouting down others' a little bit. It may be an inevitable consequence of the adversarial nature of the model - vote up, vote down, and all the rest of it.

> Is there some way we can slightly alter this to get a more desired result of less conflict, and acceptance of our differences?

I'd wish any such initiative luck, but I doubt it's going to be easy - partly because SE sites in general are a bit 'tense' compared to almost all forums I know with a similar level of seriousness, and also because I think interpersonal.SE is probably currently towards the lower end of the range when it comes to niceness on SE sites. At the risk of stating the obvious, on a site dedicated to interpersonal skills, there's always going to be a range of levels of overall interpersonal skills!

Answer (score 0):

To add a few points:

1. Solve the problem, not the person
2. Address the behavior/skill not the person.
3. Be patient
4. As this is IPS, people having questions about IPS may have poor IPS, take this into consideration
5. Be kind
6. Flag, and let it go
7. Exercise restraint, don't insult, and don't respond to insults
8. Assume the person you are addressing knows something you don't.

Comment: These are all good points.  I think they lack the Specific and Measureable aspect that is important in policies.  For example how would you objectively measure number 4.

Comment: Could you expand on number 8... maybe in its own answer.  I think that would be huge benefit personally